# Digital signature and comparing dlls in C#

Tags: c#, md5, digital-signature, authenticode

Everyday, our CI produces a bunch of dll that we need to sign and compare to a reference folder. If they change, we copy the new dll to the reference

For this i use C# to call powershell's Set-AuthenticodeSignature for signing and i compare files with MD5 checksum hashes

My issue is that i don't know how to proceed for this logic.

I can't compare 2 unsigned files because i can only store signed files in my reference.

I can't compare a signed file with an unsigned file because as far as i know, it's not possible

I can't compare 2 signed files because the signing timestamp is different for both files which result in a different hash checksum

I don't know what my approach should be.
Should i store MD5 hashes of unsigned file for reference to compare files?
Or should i create another reference folder of unsigned files?

Or is there simply a way to actually compare two signed files?
I found this post where the person tries to unsign the dll before comparing it:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/262246/how-do-i-compare-a-signed-exe-file-with-the-unsigned-version-of-the-same-exe-f

Do you have any good ideas on how to proceed for this?
My best guess is to store md5 hashes as a second reference but how do i store them efficiently? I tried mirroring the reference folder with txt file "filename.dll.md5" containing the current unsigned hash. But this doesn't seem really efficient to read and write 10k+ txt files for hash checksum

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I chose to follow a different strategy by using Alternate Data Stream (ADS)

For each assembly, i store/read the MD5 of the unsigned assembly inside the metadata of the file, which doesn't change the actual checksum of the file

You can use:
File.ReadAllText("path/to/assembly.dll:checksum")
and
File.WriteAllText("path/to/assembly.dll:checksum")
to read and write the metadata